# Skoda Fabia AC not cooling after 35-40 minutes

Tags: engine, ac, electronic-control-module, air-compressor, fabia

My 2008 Petrol skoda fabia does not cool after 35-40 minutes. The Ac blows out air but it's not cool.

Last year I had changed the compressor and condenser and the problem started since then.

Earlier my mechanic had connected a relay switch as a temporary solution to this problem connecting the compressor directly to the power without the ecm claiming the ecm was at fault. Ac worked but i was not happy with the connection as it worked only on setting 2 and fan didn't work. So i made him reverse it.

I have now changed ECM and Fuel pump but the AC problem continues to happen. To start the AC again I'll have to switch off the vehicle for a while and then start only for it to work for a few more minutes. Please help.

First 30 minutes the cooling is really cold. Scanning shows no error. Is the compressor faulty. How do i diagnose it?

Comment: One possibility is a bad expansion valve cooling the evaporator so much it freezes over. When you turn the car off it thaws and starts it to work again the next time you start it until it freezes again. A knowledgeable A.C.Tech can usually diagnose these types of problems by using a manifold gage.

Comment: Where exactly is this expansion valve located? I'm looking for a knowledgeable guy in Bangalore, India. Can't seem to find one. Thanks though

Comment: It's usually at the firewall and always just before the evaporator core. The system needs evacuated to replace it. It wouldn't be wise to replace it without a good diagnosis. That's why it is important to have a knowledgeable mechanic look at it. He can make sure that the systems charge is correct and tell you it's most likely problem. I can just tell you a most likely problem with just using information you give me. If you start replacing things on that bases, it could get very expensive. A mechanic uses the right tools can let the car tell him the problem. That's a higher chance of success.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your input. Would just like to add that the compressors center part rotates too as soon as the engine starts. Also the fan is switched on when the ac is turned on. Is this both  normal?

Comment: Yes, the center part is the pump turning this is good. The fan should be on when the pump is turning. This draws air through the condenser for proper cooling of the refrigerant.

Comment: Ok thanks. The technician said it may be because of an evap sensor in the dashboard of my car. Can it be?

Comment: Never heard of that being related to A.C. problems. Sounds like you may need a second opinion.